# ASP.Net Core with EF Core and CosmosDB - IdentityRole issue

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate my asp.net core application from using Azure SQL database to use CosmosDB database.

Facing an issue when trying to create collections with the following error messages:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'IdentityRole' has
> property 'ConcurrencyStamp' as its concurrency token, but only '_etag'
> is supported. Consider using 'EntityTypeBuilder.UseETagConcurrency'.'

I have tried these changes, none of them solve the issue.

1. I added `UseETagConcurrency` when building the model
   `builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToContainer("Roles").UseETagConcurrency();`
2. I create new derived class from `IdentityRole`, added `_etag`
   property to `Role` model

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! The issue is Role & User already have a concurrency token which is stored in the property 'ConcurrencyStamp'. So we need to tell EF that this property is what we want to use for the Etag concurrency. So instead of using `UseETagConcurrency()` use the following:

```
builder.Property(d => d.ConcurrencyStamp)
       .IsETagConcurrency();
```

Comment: thank you. it solved the issue with the creation of the collection. I am now facing an issue when trying to add role to a user by calling userManager.AddToRoleAsync. I am getting an error 
    Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: ff3980f5-90ab-4dd1-be48-e28a2b8a8575; Reason: ({
  "Errors": [
    "Resource Not Found. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"
  ]
});

Comment: i populated the UserRoles using context.UserRole as my workaround, found another issue, the user is unable to sign i
    The LINQ expression 'DbSet<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<IdentityRole>(), 
        outerKeySelector: i => i.RoleId, 
        innerKeySelector: i0 => i0.Id, 
        resultSelector: (i, i0) => new TransparentIdentifier<IdentityUserRole<string>, IdentityRole>(
            Outer = i, 
            Inner = i0
        ))' could not be translated

Comment: This might not be a good answer. `ConcurrencyStamp` is already used by MS Identity and likely coupled to the SQL server rowversion. Etag is Azure Cosmos DB specific.You might run into concurrency issues by adding this line, as the separate packages both update the property. I've seen two issues on SO already [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65359223), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66053434).

Comment: @JHBonarius Do you have any other suggestions for how to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .Property(b => b.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .IsETagConcurrency();
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>() // ApplicationUser mean the Identity user 'ApplicationUser : IdentityUser'
            .Property(b => b.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .IsETagConcurrency();

    }
```