# EF Core with Cosmos DB provider, UserManager AddLoginAsync gives ConcurrencyFailure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

Creating a new user, fetching the user again with usermanager for testing, and then using the method AddLoginAsync with the recently fetched user gives the error

> ConcurrencyFailure, Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified.

When fetching the user the "ConcurrencyStamp" has the correct etag, but after the "AddLoginAsync" I can see the user object has an invalid etag, the ConcurrencyStamp is a GUID.

I have followed the documentation and added this to the IdentityUser model configuration:

```
//builder: EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser>
builder.Property(d => d.ConcurrencyStamp)
       .IsETagConcurrency();
```

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
{
    var connectionConfig = new DbConnectionString("DefaultConnection", Configuration);
    option.UseCosmos(connectionConfig.ConnectionString, connectionConfig.Database);
});

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In the Cosmos DB Emulator I can see two documents created:

```
{
    "Id": "b66b520e-60d2-4ba3-8347-6c168be9a1e5",
    "AccessFailedCount": 0,
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-d54b-cffa72ea01d6\"",
    "Created": "2020-12-18T14:41:03.962769Z",
    "Discriminator": "ApplicationUser",
    "Email": "@email.com",
    "EmailConfirmed": false,
    "Encounters": 0,
    "LockoutEnabled": true,
    "LockoutEnd": null,
    "Nickname": null,
    "NormalizedEmail": "@EMAIL.COM",
    "NormalizedUserName": "@EMAIL.COM",
    "OrderNum": 0,
    "PasswordHash": null,
    "PhoneNumber": null,
    "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false,
    "SecurityStamp": "PPFUV4JXJ72KBYNXBPPV3FVJMIG",
    "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
    "UserName": "@email.com",
    "id": "ApplicationUser|b66b520e-60d2-4ba3-8347-6c168be9a1e5",
    "_rid": "VA5JAKKvHtQNAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/VA5JAA==/colls/VA5JAKKvHtQ=/docs/VA5JAKKvHtQNAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1608302464 }

{
    "LoginProvider": "Microsoft",
    "ProviderKey": "***",
    "Discriminator": "IdentityUserLogin<string>",
    "ProviderDisplayName": "Microsoft",
    "UserId": "b66b520e-60d2-4ba3-8347-6c168be9a1e5",
    "id": "IdentityUserLogin<string>|Microsoft|***",
    "_rid": "VA5JAKKvHtQOAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/VA5JAA==/colls/VA5JAKKvHtQ=/docs/VA5JAKKvHtQOAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-d54b-d4ad146f01d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1608302472
}
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix the issue by creating a new UserStore,

```
   public class ApplicationUserStore 
        : UserStore<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole,ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
            : base(context, describer)
        {
        }

        public override async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }

            Context.Attach(user);
            Context.Update(user);
            try
            {
                await SaveChanges(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.ConcurrencyFailure());
            }

            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

But I am now facing another issue when using signinmanager:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'DbSet<IdentityUserRole>() .Join( inner:
> DbSet(), outerKeySelector: i => i.RoleId,
> innerKeySelector: a => a.Id, resultSelector: (i, a) => new
> TransparentIdentifier<IdentityUserRole, ApplicationRole>(
> Outer = i, Inner = a ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I found the solution by overriding another method in the UserStore:

```
public override async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    string userId = user.Id;
    var roleIds = await Context.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == userId)
        .Select(ur => ur.RoleId)
        .ToArrayAsync();

    return await Context.Roles.Where(r => roleIds.Contains(r.Id))
        .Select(r => r.Name)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```