# "Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified" using cosmos with EF Core 5 and IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-5.0

I think I had this working in EF Core 3.1 (I will confirm shortly).

Here is my context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :
    IdentityDbContext<User> // User class is a simple class which inherits IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions objOptions) :
        base(objOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder objModelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(objModelBuilder);

        objModelBuilder.Entity<User>(e =>
        {
            e.ToContainer(nameof(Users));
            e.Property(i => i.ConcurrencyStamp).IsETagConcurrency();
        });

        objModelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(e =>
        {
            e.ToContainer(nameof(Roles));
            e.Property(i => i.ConcurrencyStamp).IsETagConcurrency();
        });
    }
}
```

... and some middleware

```
var objIdentityBuilder = objServices.AddIdentityCore<User>(objOptions =>
{
    // configure identity options
    objOptions.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    objOptions.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    objOptions.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    objOptions.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    objOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
});

objIdentityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(objIdentityBuilder.UserType, objIdentityBuilder.Services);
objIdentityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

... and an example of my issue

```
var objUser = await _objUserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

var objResult = await _objUserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(objUser, objModel.ResetToken, objModel.NewPassword);

if (!objResult.Succeeded)
    // Error is "Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified."
```

Any ideas why the error above is being thrown? I understand the error is saying the entity has been modified since the last save but you can clearly see in my example, it is not being modified.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: note that `e.Property(i => i.ConcurrencyStamp).IsETagConcurrency();` may be cargo cult programming. `ConcurrencyStamp` is already used by EF/SQLserver, while ETag is specific to Azure Cosmos.

Comment: by the way , there's also a `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.User` which could collide with your `User`. The name `User` is too generic and overused. Maybe change that?