# ASP.Net Core with EF Core and CosmosDB .NET 5 - IdentityRole issue

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

My Question is similar to this one.

[ASP.Net Core with EF Core and CosmosDB - IdentityRole issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291717/asp-net-core-with-ef-core-and-cosmosdb-identityrole-issue)

The provided answer does not work. It creates other issues. These errors started appearing once i upgraded my app from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5. Downgrading the app made all errors dissapear. Apparently the issue is related to the optimistic concurrency support for cosmos introduced in efcore 5.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#cosmos

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good day sir, according to your description, may I think your problem is that when you upgrade core3.1 to 5, you met the error 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'IdentityRole' has property 'ConcurrencyStamp' as its concurrency token, but only '_etag' is supported. Consider using 'EntityTypeBuilder.UseETagConcurrency'.'

' ??

Comment: Correct. This is error i am getting. As mentioned in the post i have mentioned above, I tried applying:

```
builder.Property(d => d.ConcurrencyStamp)
       .IsETagConcurrency();
```

but after applying this my identity provider is giving concurrency errors and i am unable to login.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/samples/core/Cosmos/Cosmos.csproj). I tested it in my side and it worked well.

Comment: Do you get any progress sir? Pls feel free to share your further problems if existing.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/samples/core/Cosmos/Cosmos.csproj) could help to solve your problem, I tested it in my side and it did work well.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>



using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Cosmos.ModelBuilding
{
    public class OrderContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; }

        #region Configuration
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
                "endpoint",
                "primarykey",
                databaseName: "Tasks");

        #endregion

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region DefaultContainer
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultContainer("Store");
            #endregion

            #region Container
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .ToContainer("Orders");
            #endregion

            #region NoDiscriminator
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasNoDiscriminator();
            #endregion

            #region PartitionKey
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasPartitionKey(o => o.PartitionKey);
            #endregion

            #region ETag
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .UseETagConcurrency();
            #endregion

            #region PropertyNames
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(
                o => o.ShippingAddress,
                sa =>
                {
                    sa.ToJsonProperty("Address");
                    sa.Property(p => p.Street).ToJsonProperty("ShipsToStreet");
                    sa.Property(p => p.City).ToJsonProperty("ShipsToCity");
                });
            #endregion

            #region OwnsMany
            modelBuilder.Entity<Distributor>().OwnsMany(p => p.ShippingCenters);
            #endregion

            #region ETagProperty
            modelBuilder.Entity<Distributor>()
                .Property(d => d.ETag)
                .IsETagConcurrency();
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```